# Combine 2 tables in SQL with some different column names (Transact SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge, union

I'm trying to combine multiple tables in SQL Server 2012, where some columns are the same, but others are different. I want to have them in the same table, with NULL values where data is missing.

What I want is something like union but allowing different column names.

For example,

```
Table 1:  ID | First name | Middle Name | Surname
Table 2:  ID | First name | Surname | NI
```

Would combine to produce:

```
          ID | First name | Middle Name | Surname| NI
```

with NULL values for NI for entries coming from Table 2, etc

I want to avoid creating a new table and inserting the values from the other tables, as some of my tables have over 100 columns

Comment: you're trying to create a new physical table, or you're trying to do a query to combine the results of two tables?

Comment: trying to create a new physical table

Comment: This is a simple piece of data manipulation in your text editor of choice or Excel...  Just generate the `select` statements for each table and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT [ID], [First name], [Middle Name], [Surname], NULL as [NI]
 FROM Table1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT [ID], [First name], NULL as [Middle Name], [Surname], [NI]
 FROM Table2
```

Comment: this works, but requires me to type out all my (up to 150) column names for each table

Comment: script your table out... it'll write out all of the columns for you

Comment: well sql only do what you ask it for. You have to write the query.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed like an interesting challenge and one that has bested me for now, though I got pretty far if anyone else want to try and take it further.

The script below takes in a list of table names (You could easily expand this to include schema and db if required) and builds a list of all the columns across all the tables.  It then `pivot`s on this to create a `union all` script.

The final script is currently split into three parts that could be more gracefully put together that also include a trailing `union all` in the `pivot` that has to be manually removed.  The first part is a `select null` for every column name included simply to get the column headers right in the final output.

This obviously relies on all the tables being combined having the same data types across all columns with the same names, though even if further work is required from the outputted query, it should minimise the amount of typing necessary to get the final script.

## Query

```
-- Create some dummy tables and data
create table a (a int, b int, c int, d nvarchar(500));
create table b (a int, c int, e int, f decimal(10,2));

insert into a values(1,1,1,'a');
insert into b values(2,2,2,2);


-- Create global temp tables to hold data required in the execute statement later
if object_id('tempdb..##SourceColumns') is not null
drop table ##SourceColumns;
if object_id('tempdb..##TargetColumns') is not null
drop table ##TargetColumns;


-- Find all columns in all the tables required
select t.name as TableName
        ,c.name as ColumnName
        ,ty.name as ColumnType
into ##SourceColumns
from sys.tables t
    inner join sys.columns c
        on(t.object_id = c.object_id)
    inner join sys.types ty
        on(c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id)
where t.name in('a','b')                            -- Add list of tables here
order by t.name
        ,c.column_id;



DECLARE @ColsDummy AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@Cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@Query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);


-- This is to build the start of your UNION ALL query, so that you can specify "NULL as <column name>"
set @ColsDummy = STUFF((
                    SELECT distinct ',null as ' + QUOTENAME(ColumnName)
                    FROM ##SourceColumns
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                ,1,1,'');

-- This is the list of column names to be used in the dynamically created PIVOT below
SET @Cols = STUFF((
                    SELECT distinct ', '','' as comma, ' + QUOTENAME(ColumnName)
                    FROM ##SourceColumns
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                ,1,16,'');


-- First part of final script
select 'select * from (select ''y'' as ignore, ' + @ColsDummy + ' union all';


-- Build and execute dynamic PIVOT for main part of UNION ALL query
set @Query = 'select ''select ''''n'''' as ignore,'' as [select], ' + @Cols + ', ''from '' + TableName + '' union all'' as [from]
                from 
                (
                    select TableName
                            ,ColumnName
                    from ##SourceColumns
                ) x
                pivot 
                (
                     max(ColumnName)
                    for ColumnName in (' + replace(@Cols,', '','' as comma','') + ')
                ) p
                '
execute(@Query);

-- Last part of final script
select ') a where ignore = ''n''' as [where];


-- Clean up global temp tables
if object_id('tempdb..##SourceColumns') is not null
drop table ##SourceColumns;
if object_id('tempdb..##TargetColumns') is not null
drop table ##TargetColumns;
```

---

## Output

Following removal of trailing `union all` and copying out of the three SSMS results windows:

```
select * from (select 'y' as ignore, null as [a],null as [b],null as [c],null as [d],null as [e],null as [f] union all
select 'n' as ignore,   a   ,   b   ,   c   ,   d   ,   NULL    ,   NULL    from a union all
select 'n' as ignore,   a   ,   NULL    ,   c   ,   NULL    ,   e   ,   f   from b --<union all was here>
) a where ignore = 'n'
```

---

## Result of output query

```
|ignore|  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |  e  |  f  |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|  n   |  1  |  1  |  1  |  a  | NULL| NULL|
|  n   |  2  | NULL|  2  | NULL|  2  | 2.00|
```